# Eleventy shortcodes in data content not rendering

Tags: shortcode, eleventy

I need to be able to use custom shortcodes inside content that is returned from global data using pagination.

To illustrate what I am trying to do, consider this data source :

**./site/data/article.js**

```js
module.exports = () => {
  return [
    {
      "title": "Page 1",
      "description": "Description for page 1",
      "permalink": "/sample/page1",
      "content": `## Sample Page 1
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Nam dignissim. 
    
    {% jumpto %}

    Cras faucibus at mauris 
    varius imperdiet. `
    },
    {
      "title": "Page 2",
      "description": "Description for page 2",
      "permalink": "/sample/page2",
      "content": `## Sample Page 2
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Nam dignissim. 
    
    {% jumpto %}

    Cras faucibus at mauris 
    varius imperdiet. `
    },
  ]
}
```

** NOTE ** Notice the use of `{% jumpto %}` in the code above

and here is the template for the article data ...

**./site/articles.njk**

```
---
pagination:
  data: articles
  size: 1
  alias: article
  addAllPagesToCollections: true
layout: article
permalink: "{{ article.permalink }}/"
templateEngineOverride: md, njk
eleventyComputed:
  title: "{{ article.title }}"
  description: "{{ article.description }}"
---

{{ article.content }}
```

When this rendered, it doesn't process the `{% jumpto %}` shortcodes that are returned from `article.content`.

Is there some way to inject the `article.content` into the template so that it is treated as template code?

Answer (score 1):

Nested shortcodes inside content that has itself been inserted via shortcode isn't supported currently I believe. Something like this could lead to weird infinite recursion, and open up more possibility of XSS or injection vulnerabilites if the CMS input isn't correctly escaped as is the current default.

---

To do what you are wanting, a possibility is to add a [custom filter](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/filters/) and use that in your njk file to post-process the content.

```
{{ article.content | processNestedShortcodes}}
```

---

Alternatively, if your real use case is as simple as the example code you gave above, it would be simpler to split your content input into two, and define your njk template as:

```
{{ article.content1 }}

{% jumpto %}

{{ article.content2 }}
```

Comment: Sadly my usecase is not as simple as the example.  All my content is stored in a database separate from the 11ty project.  I also can't break out the content as you have because the content is already created (thousands of files) and generously have shortcodes sprinkled throughout. @LukeStorry

Comment: The concept of creating a filter or even my own tag is still a possiblity but not very well documented.  Ideally I would want to use the `renderString` feature in nunjucks to accomplish this but it needs me to somehow connect with the overall state of the eleventy environment to really work (e.g. registered shortcodes, filters, etc)

Comment: Do you need to keep referencing that database? One way could be to run a first eleventy pass of the data to output the _site, and then copy that to another eleventy project as the input files, to eventually get the output. Could be a clean solution for a one-off build.

Comment: that isn't a bad idea.  I had a similar idea to pull the content using gulp into a build directory, then merge with the project ... and call eleventy on the combine build directory.  The advantage I have is that the source content is all markdown with nunjuck shortcodes.